# How to run code when the user presses a specific key c#

Tags: c#

how do I make this work properly? What do i need to include in my using at the top? And is this even possible?

```
internal class Program
{
    int money = 10;
    public void Water()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You spent $5 on water");
        money -= 5;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("To buy water press the w key");
        if(// w key is pressed)
        {
            Water();
        }

        //wait before closing
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have the answer already in your code. The `Console.ReadKey()` returns the key pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you meant something like this:

```
internal class Program
{
    static int money = 20;
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(BuyWater());
    }

    public static string BuyWater()
    {

        while (money > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("To buy water press the w key");
//this is where your pressed key comes in:
            if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.W)      
            // (true) is for not showing the pressed key in the console
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You spent $5 on water");
                money -= 5;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("You have $" + money);

        }
        return "You have no money left";
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this also work for numpad? or numbers in general

Comment: Yes it works for numpad and regular numbers as well. For numpad 3 for example write ConsoleKey.NumPad3 and for the regular number 3 write ConsoleKey.D3  Here's a full list of how to call all keys: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolekey?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

Console.ReadKey do exactly what you need.

```
Console.WriteLine("Press w to buy water");

if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.W)
    Water();
```